# Is complex or nested json/schema supported by confluent Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Only able to insert simple objects into db using Confluent Kafka Connect. Not sure how to make this support complex json/schema structure. I am not sure whether this feature is avalable or not. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743395/kafka-connect-how-to-fetch-nested-fields-from-struct) asked about a year ago, but not answered till now. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Kafka Connect does support complex structures, including `Struct`, `Map`, and `Array`. Generally only source connectors need to do this, as sink connectors are handed the values and simply need to use them. [This documentation](http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.1/connect/devguide.html#working-with-schemas) describes the basics of building up a `Schema` object that describes a `Struct`, and then creating a `Struct` instance that adheres to that schema. In this case, the example struct is just a flat structure.

However, you can easily add fields of type `Struct` that are defined with another `Schema` instance. In effect, it's just layering this simple pattern into multiple levels in your structs:

```
Schema addressSchema = SchemaBuilder.struct().name(ADDRESS)
    .field("number", Schema.INT16_SCHEMA)
    .field("street", Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
    .field("city", Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
    .build();
Schema personSchema = SchemaBuilder.struct().name(NAME)
    .field("name", Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
    .field("age", Schema.INT8_SCHEMA)
    .field("admin", new SchemaBuilder.boolean().defaultValue(false).build())
    .field("address", addressSchema)
    .build();

Struct addressStruct = new Struct(addressSchema)
    .put("number", 100)
    .put("street", "Main Street")
    .put("city", "Springfield")
    .build();
Struct personStruct = new Struct(personSchema)
    .put("name", "Barbara Liskov")
    .put("age", 75)
    .put("address", addressStruct)
    .build();
```

Because the `SchemaBuilder` is a fluent API, you can actually embed it just like the custom `admin` boolean schema builder. But that's a bit harder since you need to reference the `Schema` to create the `addressStruct`.

Generally you only have to worry about how to do this when writing a source connector. If you're trying to *use* an existing source connector, you likely have very little control over the structure of the keys and values. For example, [Confluent's JDBC source connector](http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.1/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html) is modeling each table with a separate `Schema` and each row in that table as a separate `Struct` that uses that schema. But since rows are flat, the `Schema` and `Struct` will only contain fields with primitive types.

[Debezium's](http://debezium.io) CDC connectors for [MySQL](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql) and [PostgreSQL](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/postgresql/) also model a relational table with a `Schema` and correspond `Struct` objects for each row, but CDC captures more information about the row such as the state of the row before and/or after the change. Consequently, these connectors use [a more complex `Schema`](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/#change-events-value) for each table that involve nested `Struct` objects.

Note that while each source connector will have their own flavor of message structures, Kafka Connect's [Single Message Transforms (SMTs)](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms) to make it pretty easy to filter, rename, and make slight modifications to the messages produced by a source connector before they are written to Kafka, or to the messages read from Kafka before they are sent to a sink connector.